# How to make a file executable in Elixir?

Tags: executable, elixir, chmod

Say I have a file that I want to turn into an executable in Elixir while preserving its original permissions. How would I go about that? Do I use `File.chmod` (and if so, how?) or `System.cmd`?

Comment: What you mean by that? Don't we run elixir programs using `elixir <file-name>` command?

Comment: No, I mean that I have a random file that I want to turn into en executable (`chmod +x filename`) through Elixir code.

Comment: I have, but when I use `System.cmd "chmod", ["+x", filename], cd: pathname`, it doesn't execute anything, as shown in the first item it returns in the tuple.

Comment: If the tuple looks like `{"", 0}`, and second element is `0`, it means it was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to use `File.chmod` as it expects non-negative integer as way to express permissions, e.g. 755, 666, etc.  This hence, requires one to set all permissions and may not allow to retain existing permissions.

```
File.chmod("file.sh", 755)
```

Hence, `System.cmd` seems like more apt way, as it executes the `chmod` system command.

```
{msg, result} = System.cmd "chmod", ["+x", filename], cd: pathname
#=> {"", 0}
```

`result` value of `0` indicates that command was successful.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Porcelain.  https://github.com/alco/porcelain Porcelain is a better way to interface to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

From what i could find in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#chmod/2) it should be

```
File.chmod(path_file, 0o755)
```